# MySQL PHP XAMPP - Conectar com o banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, conexão

Olá, estou precisando criar um webservice, mas tenho pouca experiencia com php e mysql, então tenho algumas dúvidas, estou utilizando o XAMPP e o MySQL Workbench, no workbench fiz o teste de conexão e falou que deu certo, então talvez não seja problema com o MySQL. O webService que estou criando é para disponibilizar o conteúdo do banco de dados em um JSON, bem simples mesmo. estou me baseando [nesse link](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html), se alguém tiver algum tutorial para isso. Li que talvez tenha que usar PDO, será?

```
<?php
$host="XXXXX"; //replace with database hostname 
$username="XXXXX"; //replace with database username 
$password="XXXXX"; //replace with database password 
$db_name="XXXXXX"; //replace with database name

$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select * from emp_info"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$json['emp_info'][]=$row;
}
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

O banco de dados consigo criar, assim como atualizar os valores, mas estou com esse problema e duvida se é problema com o MySQL, com o XAMPP, PHP ou é alguma configuração que falta fazer. Se alguém puder me dar alguma direção para saber o que devo correr atrás para resolver.

Comment: Você não descreveu o seu problema, mas já da pra ver que está usando `mysql_*()`, esse extensão foi descontinuada, para saber mais leia [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4675/60376)

Comment: O problema é em relação ao funcionamento, vou tentar usar outra função. Mas acho que é justamente esse, obrigado pela resposta rápida.

Comment: Complementando o que o Wellingthon disse, se estiver a usar PHP7+ não irá conseguir utilizar `mysql_...` pois nessa versão já não existe, e terá mesmo que utilizar `mysqli_...`

Answer (score -1):

Talvez sua solução para conectar no banco em PDO:

```
<?php
//inicia a conexão com dados informados
try{
$conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;
                database=banco_de_dados","login","senha");
}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getCode(); //mostra erro 
}
?>
```